# putty and X11 forwarding

Tags: xorg, putty

I think I do not understand what X11 forwarding setting in PuTTY does...

When SSH->X11 setting is unticked, but I specify the remote command "export DISPLAY=192.168.32.106:0.0; xterm" under SSH setting, then I can get remote windows displayed on my PC.

If I remove remote command and tick SSH->X11 checkbox and specify 192.168.32.106:0.0 as display location, nothing works.
After connection is established:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY

localhost:10.168
```

What do I do or understand wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should not be necessary to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable at all, provided the SSH server has defined `X11DisplayOffset`. Since you're seeing `localhost:10.168` (which is bogus) it appears that the SSH server has 10 for that setting, which is a typical default.

Simply tick the SSH > X11 box and establish a connection.  Verify the `$DISPLAY` value on the remote machine, and it should look like this:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
```

The display is `localhost` from the remote machine's point of view because SSH is intercepting that display and forwarding it back over your tunnel to your local machine.  Assuming you have an X server running on your local machine, launch an xterm or something on the remote machine and it should pop right up on your local display.

Answer (score 4):

PuTTY X11 forwarding wires an SSH tunnel so that X connections at server's localhost:10 are piped to your PC.

1. The remote X software connects to localhost:10 (localhost at the server)
2. Server **sshd** listens to server's localhost:10 and forwards to putty through SSH tunnel
3. PuTTY forwards X connection from server to localhost:0 (at your PC)

Normally X forwarding just works. Things to check:

- Is PuTTY allowed to access local X server through :0?
- Does putty know which X-server to forward to? Can PuTTY see DISPLAY=:0 environment variable?